# JavaScript / jQuery 'back button'

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JS / jQuery skills aren't great - and I'm having trouble with the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // if element exists
    if ($('.myelement').length > 0) {
        // insert html back button
        $( '.myelement' ).append( "<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>" );
        // back function
        function goBack() {
        window.history.back()
        }
    }
)};
```

I'm trying to achieve the following.
if .myelement HTML class exists
then insert back button html

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to put goBack() function outside the jquery(document).ready function ... otherwise it will not work

Comment: You also have quoting problems around `append( "<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>" )`.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple syntax problems in your script...

Apart from that the method `GoBack()` is declared in a closure scope, so in the `onclick=""` attribute handler it won't be available

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $el = $('.element');
    if ($el.length) {
        //create button
        $('<button />', {
            text: 'Go Back',
            click: function () {
                window.history.back();
            }
        }).appendTo($el); //append to .element
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            if ($('.myelement').length > 0) {
                $( '.myelement' ).append( '<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>' );
              } 
});  

 var goBack=function() {  window.history.back()  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// if element exists
var container = $('.myelement');
if (container.length > 0) {
    // insert html back button
    var backButton = $('<button></button>').text('Go Back').appendTo(container);
    backButton.on('click', function(){
        window.history.back()
    });
}
)};
```